# How to return two arrays with jsonify in Flask?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to return two different lists that are representing a chart values and labels to jsonify then to be passed to Javascript function to draw the chart, but it never worked with me. It only worked when i returned a single list for values without the labels list.

**The following is my Flask script:**

[image]

**The following is my Javascript code containing jQuery and AJAX function:**

```
    <script>

      var getValues = $.get('/data');
      getValues.done(function(values,labels){

      var data = {
        labels: [
          labels.labels
        ],

        series: [
          values.values
        ] };

        var options = {
          width : 800,
          height : 400
        }

        var myChart = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', data, options);

      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/data` endpoint returns JSON object which you can specify in your `$.get` parameter.

```
$.get('/data', function(response){
    var data = {
        labels: response.labels,
        series: [response.values]
    };

    var options = {
      width : 800,
      height : 400
    }

    var myChart = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', data, options);
}, "json");
```

Comment: At kiran.koduru another question please. I'm trying to make a different copy of this chart by creating another route in flask and duplicating the Javascript code with respecting the new $.get variables, but every time it draw the first chart and neglecting the second one.

Comment: @A.Youssef you can replace classnames to create the chart with `new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart1', data, options)` and `new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart2', data, options)`. Make sure your div class names are appropriately tagged too

Comment: @A.Youssef No problem. Cheers!