# how to get data from a jsonified page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

hi every one i have a function in flask that returns 2 jsonified lists. result & resultb and accessible on /dtt URI . ( `return jsonify({'result': a}, {'resultb': b})`  )
my problem is that when i am trying to use result or resultb i cannot use both of them. in function() i can not write function(result,resultb) and i should write on of them.

on getdata.done(function (result,resultb) when i remove result or resultb it works but i need both of them to make a chart!

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    //--basic area echarts init-->
window.setInterval(function () {

        var dom = document.getElementById("b-area1");
    var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
    var getdata= $.get('/dtt');
    getdata.done(function (result,resultb) {
            var app = {};
    option = null;
    option = {
        color: ['#8dcaf3', '#67f3e4', '#4aa9e9'],

        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis'
        },
        legend: {
            data: ['bits', 'KB']
        },

        calculable: true,
        xAxis: [
            {
                type: 'category',
                boundaryGap: false,
                data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
            }
        ],
        yAxis: [
            {
                type: 'value'
            }
        ],
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Packets',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                itemStyle: {normal: {areaStyle: {type: 'default'}}},
                data: result.result
            },

            {
                name: 'KB',
                type: 'line',
                smooth: true,
                itemStyle: {normal: {areaStyle: {type: 'default'}}},
                data: resultb.result
            }
        ]
    };


    if (option && typeof option === "object") {
        myChart.setOption(option, false);
    }


});



},7300);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the Problem ....

```
return jsonify({'result': a}, {'resultb': b})
```

this was wrong!!!
the correct form is:

```
return jsonify({'result': a, 'rs': b})
```

and then i could use response.rs or response.result on Jquery

there is some good things on this Link about my Problem :
[How to return two arrays with jsonify in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349670/how-to-return-two-arrays-with-jsonify-in-flask?rq=1)

Thank all...

Answer (score 0):

The done callback only returns one object ?

```
.done(function (response) {
  console.log(response.result, response.resultb)
}
```